# Replace string with text only when a given text precedes it

Tags: bash, sed, multiline

I have about one hundred Markdown files that contain snippets of Latex like this:

```
<div latex="true" class="task" id="Task">

(@) Delete the fourth patterns from your .teach file and your .data files. Remember to change the second line in each so that Tlearn knows there are now only three patterns.

- They should look like [@fig:dataTeach]

</div>
```

I'd like to replace the `<div>` tags with pseudotags that are easier to read, like this:

```
<task>

(@) Delete the fourth patterns from your .teach file and your .data files. Remember to change the second line in each so that Tlearn knows there are now only three patterns.

- They should look like [@fig:dataTeach]

</task>
```

This would be trivial if all my `<div>` tags were marking 'tasks', but I have similar divs for 'journal' and 'highlight'. I need a process that will change the `</div>` to `</task>` only when the preceding `<div>` has the class or id 'task', and likewise for 'journal' and 'highlight'.

Having looked around Stack Overflow for a while, I find many examples of multiline search and replace that do almost what I want to do, but the syntax (particularly for sed) is so difficult to untangle I can't adapt it for the above case. My next option is to write a bash script to loop through line by line, but I have a feeling this might be too fragile.

Cheers

Ian

Comment: sed/bash may not be the right tool for the job. This is really a task for XSLT or a proper HTML processor.

Comment: @Triptych: Generally, yes, it's always best to use a dedicated parser, but note that the OP uses _Markdown_ files, which are somewhat free-form - are there Markdown parsers you can programmatically interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `awk` command works generically, under the following assumptions:

- All opening and closing `div` tags are on their own lines.
- Attributes all use `"`-quoting.
- The new tag name is derived from the value of the `class` attribute only (this could be generalized if the rules were clearer).

```
awk -F ' class="' '
  /^<div / && NF > 1 { tag=$2; sub("\".*", "", tag); printf "<%s>\n", tag; next }
  /^<\/div>/ && tag != "" { printf "</%s>\n", tag; tag=""; next }
  1
' file
```

- `-F ' class="'` effectively splits each line into before (field 1, `$1`) and after (field 2, `$2`) the `class` attribute, if present. Only lines that have such an attribute will therefore have more than 1 field (`NF > 1`).
- Processing the opening `div` tag:

  - Pattern `/^<div / && NF > 1` therefor only matches lines that start with (`^`) `<div` and (`&&`) contain a `class` attribute (`NF > 1`)
  - `tag=$2; sub("\".*", "", tag)` extracts the `class` attribute value from the 2nd field, by replacing everything from the first `"` (the closing `"` of the attribute value) with the empty string, effectively retaining the attribute value only in variable `tag`.
  - `printf "<%s>\n", tag` prints the attribute value as the replacement opening tag.
  - `next` skips the rest of the script and moves to the next input line.
- Processing the closing `div` tag:

  - `/^<\/div>/ && tag != ""` matches the closing `div` tag, assuming that a `class` attribute value was found in the previous opening tag (`tag != ""`).
  - `printf "</%s>\n", tag` prints the new closing tag.
  - `tag=""` resets the most recent replacement tag so that any subsequent `div` elements that do not have `class` attributes don't accidentally get renamed too.
  - `next` skips the rest of the script and moves to the next input line.
- All other lines:

  - `1` simply prints all other lines as-is. (`1` is a common Awk shorthand for `{ print }`: Pattern `1`, interpreted as a Boolean, is by definition true, and a pattern without associated action `{ ... }` prints the input line by default).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$msys\bin\sed -En "s/<div latex=\"true\" class=\"task\" id=\"Task\">/<task>/;T;{:a;N;s/<\/div>/<\/task>/;Ta;p;}" input.txt
```

These are the building blocks, in case you want to adapt it:

- make a loop:`{:a;`
- it ends when the second replacement triggers: `s/<\/div>/<\/task>/;Ta;`
- only start it, if the first replacement triggered:
    `s/<div latex=\"true\" class=\"task\" id=\"Task\">/<task>/;T;`
- inside the loop just collect lines into pattern space:`N;`
- at the end of the loop just print:`p;}`
- called with extended regular expressions and without default-printing
  (mine is a windows/msys sed, just so you know):`$msys\bin\sed -En`

Comment: I feel with people not seeing through the dirty details of sed syntax. So I accpeted his the indicated amount of research (which might actually be a lot).

Comment: And yes, using a dedicated processor would probably be better. Especially because of the sed quirks. But I cannot resist an sed puzzle, when someone shows me one. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @Yunnosch... unfortunately it's not quite right for my system (macOS Sierra). I get the following error:

`invalid command code T'

Comment: Thanks for the details, @Ian Hocking. I guess there are different seds out there. Also good to know that one answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

No loop needed. Just pipe the files though this...

```
sed '/Task/s/<div.*>/<task>/g;s/<\/div>/<\/task>/g'
```

`/Task` at the beginning makes `sed` edit lines with the name `Task` in it only.

With `s/NAME/NEWNAME/` you replace some text one by one.
Adding `.*` will replace all text starting at this point.

Last but not least, `g` stands for global and will edit all entries this way.

Second command (after `;`) will replace `</div>` with `</task>`. Its a part of the same command like before. The difference this time is that a `/` (slash) will be used by `sed` it self, if not declared other wise! This can be archived via a `\` (backslash).

Here you go. The output of your file will look like this....

```
<task>

(@) Delete the fourth patterns from your .teach file and your .data files. Remember to change the second line in each so that Tlearn knows there are now only three patterns.

- They should look like [@fig:dataTeach]

</task>
```

Comment: This will substitute `</div>` with `</task>` every single time, but it should only do so if the preceding opening `<div>` was a `"task"` div.

Comment: Thanks, suleiman, but @Benjamin W. is correct---this doesn't take account of the context.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
v='task|journal|highlight'
sed -ri '/^<div/{:a;N;/^<\/div/M!ba;s/^<.*class="('$v')"[^>]*(.*<\/)div/<\1\2\1/}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

This stores the `div` statements in the pattern space and then substitutes (or not) the required values depending on the shell variable set beforehand.

N.B. the alternatives are stored in the shell variable `v` separated by `|`

Comment: Thanks, @potong---unfortunately I can't test this. My sed (on macOS Sierra) fails with the error:

`illegal option -- r`